# Blocking facebook app in sonic wall

Tags: sonicwall

we have sonicwall TZ 210 and most of the licenses have expired. I have to block facebook apps, youtube and so on from mobile users as well as workstations. 
As i followed the guide for this configuration, 
https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw8620
I get this error when i go to firewall>app control advanced
[image]

i was told that the firewall was reconfigured some time ago and before that application such as facebook youtube was blocked. So what are the alternatives for this one?

Please help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have valid licenses to use Advanced Services as Content Filtering or App control. There are no alternative to this. Just check in www.mysonicwall.com what license do you have for your device.

If your license are still valid, you need to resync or re-register the device.
If your license expired, only option is renewing it (paying it of course :P)

Comment: the time problem, is it because of not having a valid license?